# overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DataBind' is most specific for these arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am getting this error 'overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DataBind' is most specific for these arguments' below is the code I am using.

```
    Private Overloads Sub DataBind(ByVal iPageIndex As Integer) 
     //do some thing 
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub DataBind(raiseondatabinding as Boolean)
        //Do some thibg
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
            DataBind(Nothing) //this is where I am getting error
    End Sub
```

Any help would be appropriated.

Thanks,

Pradeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't know which version of `DataBind` you're trying to use, because `Nothing` is convertible to both `Boolean` and `Integer`. You could either use a variable for this:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                            ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs) _
                            Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim x As Integer = Nothing
    DataBind(x)
End Sub
```

or just specify `0` or `False` as the argument:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                            ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs) _
                            Handles btnSearch.Click
    DataBind(False)
End Sub
```

Adjust depending on which version you *actually* wanted to call. Like the compiler, I can't tell what you intended :)